# Update stock of product option on opencart

Tags: php, opencart

What I want is to change stock status depending on what configurations is selected.

If a product option have the stock option with quantity 0 show "Out of stock" or is quantity 50 show "Available" and when is quantity -1 show "Pre order"

```
if ($product_option_value['quantity'] <= -1) {
            $this->data['stock'] = $product_info['stock_status'];
        } elseif ($this->config->get('config_stock_display')) {
            $this->data['stock'] = $product_info['quantity'];
        } else {
            $this->data['stock'] = $this->language->get('text_preorder');


if ($product_option_value['quantity'] <= 0) {
            $this->data['stock'] = $product_info['stock_status'];
        } elseif ($this->config->get('config_stock_display')) {
            $this->data['stock'] = $product_info['quantity'];
        } else {
            $this->data['stock'] = $this->language->get('text_outstock');
        }



if ($product_option_value['quantity'] => 50) {
            $this->data['stock'] = $product_info['stock_status'];
        } elseif ($this->config->get('config_stock_display')) {
            $this->data['stock'] = $product_info['quantity'];
        } else {
            $this->data['stock'] = $this->language->get('text_instock');
        }
```

Comment: So what's the issue that need to be solved?

Comment: It won't work as `$this->data['stock'] = $this->language->get('text_instock');` - this piece of code `else` will always get rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($product_option_value['quantity'] <= 0) {
    $this->data['stock'] = $this->language->get('text_outstock');
} elseif ($product_option_value['quantity'] => 50) {
    $this->data['stock'] = $product_info['stock_status'];
} elseif ($this->config->get('config_stock_display')) {
    $this->data['stock'] = $product_info['quantity'];
}else {
    $this->data['stock'] = $this->language->get('text_instock');
}
```

-- I think this much code is enough, change the value assigned to `$this->data['stock']` as per your requirements.

Comment: what's the output? and what's the expected output?

Comment: if ($product_info['quantity'] <= 0) {
    $this->data['stock'] = $product_info['stock_status'];
   } elseif ($this->config->get('config_stock_display')) {
    $this->data['stock'] = $product_info['quantity'];
   } else {
    $this->data['stock'] = $this->language->get('text_instock');
   }

Comment: Where does this code go? I'm trying to accomplish the same thing